The restriction of a non-self-intersecting immersed curve to an proper open subset is an embedding
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an open interval and let $\gamma:(a,b) \rightarrow M$ a smooth curve which is an injective smooth immersion. I would like to prove that for all $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<c<d<b$, the restriction of $\gamma$ to $(c,d)$ is a smooth embedding.
I have tried to use the Local Slice Criterion for Embedded Submanifolds (Theorem 5.8 in the book 'Introduction to smooth manifolds' by John M. Lee) without success.
Any hint or help will be really appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Hint: restrict $\gamma$ to $[c,d]$ and use that $[c,d]$ is compact.

Thank you so much !!! ❤️ Since $[c,d]$ is compact, $M$ is a Hausdorff space and $\gamma$ is an injective continuous map, then $\gamma|{[c,d]}$ is a topological embedding, because $\gamma|{[c,d]}$ is a closed map. And so, the restriction of $\gamma|_{[c,d]}$ to $(c,d)$ is also a topological embedding.
